# ckeditor image plugin for selecting image to upload

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

Here, I am using ckeditor and I want to upload an image using ckeditor.
I found link and I did like it says but I couldn't get button to upload an image for that.
[Link](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image) is here for an image. My ckeditor version is CKEditor 4.5.6.
What can I do for upload an image?

Answer (score 0):

Do remember that by default CKEditor does not include a file manager/uploader, so you need to integrate some server-side component to handle that. It can be either [CKFinder](https://cksource.com/ckfinder) (the file manager created by CKSource, the company behind CKEditor that can be easily integrated with the editor), some third-party product of your choice or your own solution.

Please refer to the CKEditor documentation about file upload - there is plenty of it, including samples with source code ready to copy and use in your own implementation:

- [File Upload through Dialogs and Drag&Drop](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html) sample
- [File Manager Integration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browse_upload) documentation.
- [CKFinder Integration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_ckfinder_integration) documentation
- [File Browser API - Creating a Custom File Manager](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api) documentation
- [CKFinder + CKEditor demo](https://cksource.com/ckfinder/demo#ckeditor)

Answer (score 0):

Image upload in server and set url in ckeditor

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jqy4ni <== demo link for angular

```
<ckeditor  [editor]="editor" 
[config]=" {
  ckfinder: {
    options: {
      resourceType: 'Images'
    },
    uploadUrl: "BACK_END_MAPPING_URL_FOR_SAVE_IMG
  },

}"
rows="6">   </ckeditor>


=> for back end use file name "upload"
 Ex. 
  @RequestParam(value = "upload") List<MultipartFile> multipartFile

And response
 FOR SUCCESS ================
    {
          "uploaded": true,
          "url": "http://file/img/get_image_url.jpeg"
      } 
 FOR ERROR ================
   { 
         "uploaded": false,
          "error": {
              "message": "could not upload this image"
          }
    }
```